# Bold font weight doesn't work when using Bootstrap stylesheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues will bold text when using bootstrap. Text that should be bold is not displayed as bold in Chrome:

[image]

However in Safari it works as expected:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Font check</title>

<!--  Comment out the bootstrap stylesheet and it works  -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-test.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Hello World!</h1> -->
<span class="bold-text">Hello World!</span>
```

CSS:

```
* {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
.bold-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/Kexarif/pen/rNOZMqO

It was suggested that I needed to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` but that makes no difference.

If I comment out the Bootstrap stylesheet the text is displayed correctly in Chrome. So it seems to be because of the Bootstrap. Any ideas why this might be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: it seems like codepen demo is working fine on chrome. font's bold

Comment: It's not displaying correctly on my machine. Strange. Could it be related to system fonts or something?

Answer (score 0):

try **Clear browsing data**, one day it's work for me

Comment: Tried this didn't work. See the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually a Chrome bug. It causes some of the system stack fonts to not display bold text correctly. It will be a few weeks until there is a fix, source: https://css-tricks.com/chrome-system-fonts-snafu

For now a temp fix is:

```
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, Helvetica;
}
```